# Can't overwrite a file wrapped in a using statement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm building an app that is supposed to do the following :

- User selects an element in a listbox (**example : frog**)
- A picture corresponding to the element is opened as the background on a canvas, on which the user can draw
- When the user selects another element of the listbox, the canvas is saved as a picture named after the unchecked element, with "New" added (**example : frogNew**)
- This new element is added to the listbox, and if the user edits it again, it is saved under *the same name* (**example : frogNew**)

Things are working out, except the part where I try to save a canvas under the same name (frogNew). I get an error saying that I cannot save the file as it is already open. Can you tell me where if don't close the file properly in my code ?

```
private void save_picture(string name)
{
    //This part takes a screenshot of the canvas, named "paintSurface"
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)paintSurface.RenderSize.Width, (int)paintSurface.RenderSize.Height, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(paintSurface);
    BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    //If the file already exists, we add "New" to its name
    var regex1 = new Regex(@"New$");
    if (regex1.Match(nom).ToString() == "")
    {
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\Test" + name + "New.png"))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(fs);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\Test" + name + ".png"))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(fs);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //When the index of listbox changes, I save the canvas in a file named after the former index
    List<string> oldItemNames = new List<string>();
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        var oldPhoto = e.RemovedItems[0].ToString();
        save_picture(oldPicture);
    }
    //I start a new canvas with the picture corresponding to the new index as a background
    paintSurface.Children.Clear();
    ImageBrush newBrush = new ImageBrush();
    newBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\Test" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    paintSurface.Background = newBrush;                        
}
```

Any idea why this line "`using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\Test" + name + ".png"))"` always gives me the error that this file is already open ? How can I close it?

Comment: The problem is probably your `BitmapEncoder` (`pngEncoder`), have you tried closing/disposing that object?

Comment: No, I didn't. Would you mind telling me how to properly do it ?

Comment: @LoukoumMira `Dispose()` it or wrap in in a `using` as well.

Comment: Try to use `FileStream` instead of `OpenWrite`. `BitmapEncoder` is not disposable.

Comment: I think you're missing a slash in the file path. Your current thing is trying to create a file called  D:\TestfrogNew.png

Comment: I had to remove it when posting on stackoverflow because it was messing with the rest of the code, nice find though haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your file is locked by the `BitmapImage` that you're using as the image source

You need to specify the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` option while initializing the bitmap image:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"D:\Test" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative);
bitmapImage.EndInit();

newBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's your save operation keeping the file open. It's the read operation near the end of your code sample. You open FooNew.png, edit it, and try to write to the same file.

Try this. Where you have:

```
newBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\Test" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Replace with:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Test" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".png"))
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = fileStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    newBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
}
```

Once you get this working, you're going to realize that `File.OpenWrite()` isn't what you want in `save_picture`. It would append the new PNG to any existing file contents. You want `File.Create()` which creates a new file or overwrites an existing one.

Comment: Yes you are right, this was the problem, dynamoid gave the answer just a couple minutes before though. Thanks anyway !